# How to change OrmLite's encoding?

Tags: java, ormlite

I have this method:

```
@Override
public List<Biblioteczka> wyswietlenieKsiazek() throws SQLException
{
    Dao<Biblioteczka,String>biblioteczkaDao=DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource,Biblioteczka.class);
    Where<Biblioteczka,String>queryBuilder=biblioteczkaDao.queryBuilder().where().eq("Rodzaj","Książka");
    PreparedQuery<Biblioteczka>preparedQuery=queryBuilder.prepare();
    List<Biblioteczka>lista=biblioteczkaDao.query(preparedQuery);
    return lista;
}
```

It should execute this query:

```
select * from Zbiory where Rodzaj="Książka"
```

But OrmLite doesn't understand the word "Książka" (because of "ą" and "ż") so I have 0 results:

```
2015-06-04 20:11:21,456 [DEBUG] DaoManager created dao for class class Biblioteczka with reflection
2015-06-04 20:11:21,468 [DEBUG] StatementBuilder built statement SELECT * FROM `Zbiory` WHERE `Rodzaj` = 'Książka' 
2015-06-04 20:11:21,807 [DEBUG] JdbcConnectionSource opened connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Biblioteka got #914810065
2015-06-04 20:11:21,823 [DEBUG] BaseMappedStatement prepared statement 'SELECT * FROM `Zbiory` WHERE `Rodzaj` = 'Książka' ' with 0 args
2015-06-04 20:11:21,827 [DEBUG] SelectIterator starting iterator @479233124 for 'SELECT * FROM `Zbiory` WHERE `Rodzaj` = 'Książka' '
2015-06-04 20:11:21,828 [DEBUG] SelectIterator closed iterator @479233124 after 0 rows
2015-06-04 20:11:21,828 [DEBUG] StatementExecutor query of 'SELECT * FROM `Zbiory` WHERE `Rodzaj` = 'Książka' ' returned 0 results
2015-06-04 20:11:22,558 [DEBUG] JdbcConnectionSource closed connection #914810065
```

How to fix that?
I'm using MySQL. Default collation: utf8_general_ci, default characterset: utf8, table collation: utf8_general_ci.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your application and database both understand UTF-8. What about your DB driver? Make sure the connection string to MySQL (assuming you use MySQL based on the log you provided) contains `characterEncoding` and `useUnicode` parameters

```
jdbc:mysql://server:post/deName?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

if that doesn't help you can try heavy machinery

```
character_set_client=UTF-8&character_set_database=UTF-8&character_set_results=UTF8&character_set_server=UTF-8&character_set_system=UTF-8
```

and finally init the db connection with

```
set names utf8
```

Also make sure all the source files are actually UTF-8.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thx u so much, it works! Your first advice helped me.